# When to use Test&Set or Test&Test&Set?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, x86, parallel-processing

Parallel programming under x86 can be hard job especially under multi-core CPU.
Let say that we have multi-core x86 CPU and more different multithread communication combinations.

1. Single writer and single reader
2. Single reader multiple writers
3. Multiple readers and single writer
4. Multiple readers and multiple writers

So which one model is better (more efficient) for locking shared memory region: **Test&Set**  or **Test&Test&Set** and when to use it!

Here I have two simple (no time limited) test procedures written in under Delphi IDE in x86 assembler:

```
procedure TestAndSet(const oldValue, newValue: cardinal; var destination);
asm
//eax = oldValue
//edx = NewLockValue
//ecx = destination = 32 bit pointer on lock variable 4 byte aligned
@RepeatSpinLoop:
        push    eax                   //Save lock oldValue (compared)
        pause                         //CPU spin-loop hint
        lock    cmpxchg dword ptr [ecx], edx
        pop     eax                   //Restore eax as oldValue
        jnz     @RepeatSpinLoop       //Repeat if cmpxchg wasn't successful
end;

procedure TestAndTestAndSet(const oldValue, newValue: cardinal; var destination);
asm
//eax = oldValue
//edx = NewLockValue
//ecx = destination = 32 bit pointer on lock variable 4 byte aligned
@RepeatSpinLoop:
        push    eax                   //Save lock oldValue (compared)
@SpinLoop:
        pause                         //CPU spin-loop hint
        cmp     dword ptr [ecx], eax  //Test betfore test&set
        jnz     @SpinLoop
        lock    cmpxchg dword ptr [ecx], edx
        pop     eax                   //Restore eax as oldValue
        jnz     @RepeatSpinLoop       //Repeat if cmpxchg wasn't successful
end;
```

**EDIT:**

Intel in documentation mention two approach **Test&Set  or Test&Test&Set**. I' wont to establish in which case is someone approach better, so when to use it. Check: [Intel](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/win/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_pause.htm?wapkw=%28pause%29)

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: I hope that my answer was clear: which approach is better and when, of course if somebody have any expirience about.

Comment: @GJ: the sample you have linked to uses `xchg`, not `cmpxchg`.

Comment: @andras: yes but the Test&Test&Set logic is the same, it is possible also to use xchg instead cmpxchg, but than you must to compare the return exchanged value to be sure if lock was set.

Comment: @GJ: `xchg` is unconditional, while `cmpxchg` is conditional. The latter may offer chip designers more opportunities for optimization. That is why I mentioned that your results may vary if you compare its performance on say a Pentium Pro and a Core i7.

Comment: @andras: thanks, however generally the "cmpxchg" is probably slower than "xchg" because maybe takes more CPU cycles to hold lock on the memory bus. The xchg is usefull only for simple locks with two states True and False like bit test and set "lock bts" instruction. I will try to compare boath intrinsics.

Comment: @GJ: Your assumption is wrong. `cmpxchg` will generally not assert the LCK signal on the bus on modern CPUs.

Comment: @andras: Yes, but I must to use it together with **lock** if I wont to ensure atomic execution in shared memory. At the **xchg** intrinsic the **lock** prefix is executed automaticly. I predict that **lock cmpxchg** will take more lock memory bus cycles than **xchg**. That is propably a reason whay upper Intel reference use **xchg** instead **lock cmpxchg**.

Comment: @GJ: `upper Intel reference` is a bit out-of-date. You should be able to find up-to-date developer pdf manuals on Intel site.

Comment: @GJ: you're welcome. I've updated my answer, if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TTAS (#2) is good practice. "Lurking" and waiting for the "opportunity" before doing `CAS` is common practice in both Java and .NET concurrent classes. With that said, `cmpxchg` received quite a lot of optimizations in the last few years, so it might be possible that you'd get nearly identical results on the latest crop of processors.

What you should try in both cases, however is to employ some [exponential backoff](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs176/ch07.ppt) when you spin.

**Update**

@GJ: You should find [some more up-to-date documentation on Intel's site](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-scalable-atomic-locks-for-multi-core-intel-em64t-and-ia32-architectures/?wapkw=%28Implementing+Scalable+Atomic+Locks+Multi%29). Note the paragraph about not locking the bus since 486 and the comparison chart of `xchg` and `cmpxchg` that shows that they are practically identical.

Spinning on a read vs on a `locked` instruction will still be a good idea to avoid some contention on getting the cache line in exclusive mode. (So TTAS.)

However this will provide a useful gain only if you implement e.g. an exponential back-off, even yielding the CPU after a while.

The differences between TTAS and TAS, or w/o backoff would be smaller if you are using a single, modern multi-core CPU with a shared L3 cache between the cores and would become more visible if you are using a multi-socket  - e.g. server - machine or a multi-core CPU that has no shared cache between the cores. They would also be different based on the amount of contention. (I.e. light load would see smaller difference between TTAS/TAS.)

Comment: Tkanks for help, link is also very useful. :)

Answer (score 3):

Surely the first (testAndSet) is better because the 2nd does not achieve much with repeating the test using cmp & jnz - in between. While you are doing this the destination value may change anyway as it is not locked.

Comment: Not sure... The modern CPUs use cache, the "lock" instruction will made the cache update for all cores and this take some time, check Intel documentacion. Continually (in spin-loop) locking the memory bus will decrease the speed of all other threads.

Comment: @GJ: in order to be sure.... use a timer! And it will depend heavily on the CPU it runs on. For instance a mono-core Pentium 4 won't handle it the same way as a Core i7... And you're 100% right when saying than the lock is slower than the plain cmp.

Comment: @GJ I'm sure you are aware that the pause instruction is equivalent to a few NOP instructions. Designed that way so you you do NOT sit in an extremely tight loop. So I would use what the designers gave me for that very purpose. P.S. It's 15 years since I did any assembler :)

Comment: about the pause instruction, it's not anymore the case. It was designed in order to be specifically called within spin loops, in modern CPUs. But the implementation depends on the CPU it runs on. For instance, some are faster with a rep nop, other with a rep pause, or a single pause... there is no unique solution here!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the 2nd approch, a test with not lock, then a lock if the test sucessed, with some proposals:

- use call SwitchToThread instead of pause
- put a call SwitchToThread in the not-locked repeat cmp loop
- put the call SwitchToThread only in case of the cmp/lock failure

In all cases, I think you'd better:

- use Windows API for your synchronization, if you really want to handle low-level synchronization in your project, see [Synchronization Functions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686360%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - Microsoft made the low-level and optimization work for you. Most of these calls are optimized asm code, running in user mode, so are very fast.
- use a high-level multi-thread framework, which in practice will handle all these problems for you, and will definitively scale well - see the [Delphi OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/)
- use a dedicated memory manager, like [NexusMM](http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=node/522), [TBBMM](http://www.zachsaw.co.cc/?pg=borlndmm_tbbmm), or [ScaleMM](http://code.google.com/p/scalemm/)/[SynScaleMM](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=772)

Comment: 1)Yes becouse the second approch is Test&Test&Set. 2)Thanks for SwitchToThread I'm already using it, this is only a simplified test case and the lock time should be very short. 3)API synchronizations calls are to slow. 4)I'm familiar with OmniThreadLibrary and I'm also contributor

Comment: @GJ: OK - did you try putting your pause only if the first unlocked cmp fails? Some articles say that rep nop could be faster than rep pause which could be faster than a plain pause. Depends on the CPU and the OS... :(

Comment: I fixed your links. Please read the editing FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for embedding your links (you can click the "edited" link above my picture: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4301722/revisions)